# How do I get a mango seed to go from the first shoot to a healthy plant?

Tags: fruit-trees, germination

I followed a video I found on youtube (can't find it again now), which said to wrap the seed in damp paper and leave in a plastic bag for a few weeks until the root and shoot started sprouting. I did that, then planted in a mixture of potting mixture, sphagnum and perlite.

The shoot started growing, but after it got about an inch or so high, it withered away and died. I have two more wrapped up, and would like some advice on how to get them from that first stage to a healthy plant. Specifically, any advice on watering and feeding would be welcome.

I live in the UK, and they would be placed on a very bright west-facing windowsill that gets a lot of sunshine (when we have it!).

Thanks

Comment: Growing mango from seeds in UK brings 2 problems/difficulties. First, the mangoes are harvested unripe which means that the seeds are also underdeveloped. Second, most mangoes are treated with gamma radiation which causes mutations in the DNA of the seeds. So these two handicaps make it very difficult to get a successful plant from seed.

Comment: @benn oh, that's a shame, I was hoping we could at least get a plant. I'll see what happens with the ones I have already, and if that doesn't work, I'll stick to avocados! Thanks